# How to write arrays from a form separately?

Tags: javascript, php, html

Good afternoon, I'm still just learning, and I had such a problem, I googled it for 2 days, but in the end I found a solution, tell me how can I implement this?
I have a dynamic form, at the output I get an array in the format

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customerName] => 
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test1
                            [1] => Test2
                            [2] => Test3
                        )

                    [productPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123
                            [1] => 321
                            [2] => 231
                        )

                    [competitor1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 
                            [1] => 
                            [2] => 
                        )

                    [product1] => 
                    [competitorPrice1] => 
                    [competitor2] => 
                    [product2] => 
                    [competitorPrice2] => 
                    [competitor3] => 
                    [product3] => 
                    [competitorPrice3] => 
                    [minPrice] => 
                )

            [submit] => Отправить запрос
        )

)
```

But I need it to be

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [customerName] =>
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test1

                        )

                    [productPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 123

                        )

                    [competitor1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] =>
                        )

                    [product1] =>
                    [competitorPrice1] =>
                    [competitor2] =>
                    [product2] =>
                    [competitorPrice2] =>
                    [competitor3] =>
                    [product3] =>
                    [competitorPrice3] =>
                    [minPrice] =>
                )

            [submit] => Отправить запрос
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [customerName] =>
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test2

                        )

                    [productPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 321

                        )

                    [competitor1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] =>
                        )

                    [product1] =>
                    [competitorPrice1] =>
                    [competitor2] =>
                    [product2] =>
                    [competitorPrice2] =>
                    [competitor3] =>
                    [product3] =>
                    [competitorPrice3] =>
                    [minPrice] =>
                )

            [submit] => Отправить запрос
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [customerName] =>
            [items] => Array
                (
                    [product] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => Test3

                        )

                    [productPrice] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => 231

                        )

                    [competitor1] => Array
                        (
                            [0] =>
                        )

                    [product1] =>
                    [competitorPrice1] =>
                    [competitor2] =>
                    [product2] =>
                    [competitorPrice2] =>
                    [competitor3] =>
                    [product3] =>
                    [competitorPrice3] =>
                    [minPrice] =>
                )

            [submit] => Отправить запрос
        )

)
```

I can't save it, please help

My code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form class="" action="index.php" method="post" name="">
      <p>
        <input name="customerName" placeholder="Enter customer name">
      </p>
      <table>
        <tr name="myarr">
          <th>#</th>
          <th>Товар</th>
          <th>Цена</th>
          <th>Конкурент №1</th>
          <th>Товар конкурента №1</th>
          <th>Цена конкурента №1</th>
          <th>Конкурент №2</th>
          <th>Товар конкурента №2</th>
          <th>Цена конкурента №2</th>
          <th>Конкурент №3</th>
          <th>Товар конкурента №3</th>
          <th>Цена конкурента №3</th>
          <th>Минимальная цена</th>
        </tr>
        <tbody id="tbody"></tbody>
      </table>

      <p>
        <button type="button" onclick="addItem();">
          Add Item
        </button>
      </p>

      <p>
        <input type="submit" name="submit">
      </p>
    </form>

    <script>
      var items = 0;
      function addItem() {
        items++;
        var html = "<tr>";
          html += "<td>" + items + "</td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[product][]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[productPrice][]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[competitor1][]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[product1]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[competitorPrice1]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[competitor2]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[product2]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[competitorPrice2]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[competitor3]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[product3]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[competitorPrice3]'></td>";
          html += "<td><input name='items[minPrice]'></td>";
        html += "<tr>";
        document.getElementById('tbody').insertRow().innerHTML = html;
      }
    </script>
    <script>

    </script>
  </body>
</html>

<?php

  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $data = array();
    $data[] = $_POST;
    echo '<pre>';
    print_r($data);
    echo '<pre>';
    $fp = fopen('results.json', 'w');
    fwrite($fp, json_encode($data));
    fclose($fp);
  }



?>
```

I tried to iterate over the first array and split it,
but nothing happened

I need this in order to calculate the total amount of goods, and display it all as a table in excel

Comment: You can make your desired output with php. I think there is no way to get that array structure with html form!

Comment: Put one more square bracket eg ```items[product][][]```

Comment: you can put the name like this 
name="items['+items+'][product]"

Comment: Adding a new form stops working